# Troubles while running neo4j & rails in HA

Tags: neo4j

I have configured an HA cluster with 3 nodes.
The first is a Rails server, and the others are two Neo4j server

I started the Rails s, then I started another instance, with the following error

Has anyone an idea?

Paolo

---

2013-11-21 23:48:57.473+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Attempting to join cluster of [127.0.0.1:5001, 127.0.0.1:5002, 127.0.0.1:5003]
2013-11-21 23:49:02.568+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Joined cluster:Name:neo4j.ha Nodes:{1=cluster://127.0.0.1:5001, 3=cluster://127.0.0.1:5003} Roles:{coordinator=1}
2013-11-21 23:49:02.582+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 3 (this server) joined the cluster
2013-11-21 23:49:06.845+0000 INFO  [Cluster] Instance 1 was elected as coordinator
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2598)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1318)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.member.paxos.PaxosClusterMemberEvents$HighAvailabilitySnapshotProvider.setState(PaxosClusterMemberEvents.java:179)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotMessage$SnapshotState.setState(SnapshotMessage.java:91)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotState$2.handle(SnapshotState.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.protocol.snapshot.SnapshotState$2.handle(SnapshotState.java:89)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachine.handle(StateMachine.java:88)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.StateMachines$1.run(StateMachines.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: more... information... required... **PLEASE** [follow these guidlines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: please share the config for all 3